# How should I split my php files so that html forms don't break my code?

Tags: php, html

In my current website project I have chunks of php and html code that are repeated throughout the project. For example, every page has the same header and footer as all the others. So, for the sake of modularizing my code I have created separate php files for things like these. Here is an example of my header.php file.

```
//header.php
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submittext'])) {
        echo $_POST['sometext'];
    }

?>
<div id="header">
    <form action="header.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="sometext">
        <input type="submit" name="submittext">
    </form>

    <div id="somediv">
        <?php
            //Some more php
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is an example of a file that contains code for things unique to the page, unlike the header or footer. Call this file home.php.

```
//home.php
<?php
    //Some php 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Style sheets, etc. -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('header.php'); ?> //Here I include the above file

        <div id="main">
            <!-- Html for everything below the header -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that I have a form in the header.php file. So when I submit the form, the action attribute says to reload header.php. But if it does that, then the other code in home.php doesn't load such as the "main" div. So my question is, how can I modularize my code to prevent very long and hard to read php files, while also being able to load all my content? My first idea was to just put `header('Location: home.php');` after I process the form in the header.php file, but then if I include the header.php file in another page, say home2.php, it will redirect me back to home.php rather than home2.php.

Comment: `the action attribute says to reload header.php` But it doesn't? It says `post.php`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say header.php

Comment: Well... don't put `header.php` there if that's not what you want.

Comment: header.php is what I want to have as the action attribute. post.php was there because it was a typo, which I had fixed before your second comment. The reason why I want header.php as the action is because I want to modularize my code so that the php code that deals with processing the form in header.php stays in the header.php file.

Comment: I'm completely confused as to what problem you're having. Maybe someone else will figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a simple pure php router, you can load multiple views in a modular sense that you might be looking for by simply calling routes on your site. So `example.com` would fall under the `null` route, and you could have your views render there, and then you could have a `example.com/home2` route which would display all your views for that particular route.

In doing this, you can then tell your `post.php` page to redirect to different routes and render all the modular component views you may need for that page.This method also cleans up the URL and shows `/home` instead of `home.php`.

Put this code in your index.php file.

```
$site_url = 'www.example.com';

function getCurrentUri()
{
    $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', 
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
    if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
    $uri = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
    return $uri;
}

$base_url = getCurrentUri();
$routes = array();
$routes = explode('/', $base_url);
foreach($routes as $route)
{
    if(trim($route) != '')
        array_push($routes, $route);
}
switch($routes[1]) {
    case('home2'):
      $page = 'home2';
      include('header.php');
      include('home2.php');
      include('footer.php');
    break;       
    case(null):
      $page = 'home';
      include('header.php');
      include('home.php');        
      include('footer.php');
    break;
    default:
        header('Location: http://'. $site_url .'/404');
    break;
}
```

You might also need a `.htaccess` file in your base directory to allow for the rewrites so try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But don't quote me on that ^^ htaccess syntax is confusing.

Also sidenote, it would be better practice to put the full `<html><head>` and start of the `<body>` tag in the `header.php` file instead of again rewriting that code for your other pages when you could just include a full html head.

So essentially this would become your `header.php`

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
      <!-- Style sheets, etc. -->
  </head>
  <body>
     <?php include('header.php'); ?> //Here I include the above file
```

Which very well could solve your problem, if you then redirected to `home.php` and at the top before your home page code you included the `header.php`

Comment: For the routing part, am I supposed to just put `header('Location: index.php');` at the end of my first php block in header.php? And then the code in index.php will redirect me back to home.php? And for the html part of your response, if I do as you said won't I then have two doctypes and two html tags in my home.php? I say that because I would be including them in a file that already has them? I thought that breaks it and or is illogical because header.php isn't supposed to be a standalone page.

Comment: The .htaccess will send all traffic through index.php.  index.php will then take apart the pieces of the url and determine which content to include. You don't want to put any `header('Location: ...)` commands in your views because 1) headers don't work after output and 2) You don't want to redirect at this point anyway.

Comment: Use the switch statement to pass the value for the action attribute in the form in the header.

Comment: To make your php files modular as youd like, the home.php should only have the code in your `<div id="main">`. Then above that you would include the `header.php` file which should have the full `<doctype html><html><head>` tags. Then after your home page content you would include the `footer.php` which would have the closing `<body><html>` tags.

Comment: The router and switch statement in the index.php file then would work by simply redirecting to `/home` or `/whatever` and the views you want to be returned will show up

Comment: Ah, I have figured it out. Thank you for your help, and sorry for the late reply.